# How to make the vibrate different according to the significant light value?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-sensors

I want the app to vibrate accordingly to the light value detected. For example, when the value is higher then the vibration is stronger. But this code seems not working, anyone can help to see where is my mistake? It can detect the light value correctly and the vibration is working but the vibration is not vibrating according to the light value.

```
 public class LightDetection extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView textLight, textOn, textOff;
    Button btnStart, btnStop;
    float x;
    long ambientValue = 16;
    long floor_delay = 500;
    long ceiling_delay = 80;
    long vibrate = 100;
    long vibrate_delay;
    Vibrator sensorVibrator;
    SensorManager sensorManager;
    Sensor sensor;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_light_detection);

    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    sensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT);
    sensorVibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    textLight = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textOn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    textOff = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    btnStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);


    final SensorEventListener lightListener = new SensorEventListener() {
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int acc) {
        }

        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
            float x = event.values[0];
            Log.i("IE LightDetect.", "Light value: " + x);
            textLight.setText((int) x + " lux");
        }
    };

    btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        public void onClick(View view) {
            sensorManager.registerListener(lightListener, sensor,
                    SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, vibrate_delay);
            textOn.setText("LIGHT DETECTION MODE: ON");
        }
    });

    btnStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        public void onClick(View view) {
            textOn.setText("LIGHT DETECTION MODE: OFF");
            sensorManager.unregisterListener(lightListener);
            sensorVibrator.cancel();
            handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);

        }
    });



}

private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        /* do what you need to do */
        long luxValue = (long) x;
        //Correction Ratio - Ceiling Delay/Most Likely Max Lux
        long ratio = 950 / 300;

        if (luxValue < ambientValue) {
            vibrate = 100;
            vibrate_delay = floor_delay + (ratio * luxValue);
        } else {
            vibrate = 100;
            vibrate_delay = floor_delay - (ratio * luxValue);
        }

        if (vibrate_delay < ceiling_delay) {
            long[] pattern = {0, vibrate, ceiling_delay};
            sensorVibrator.vibrate(pattern, 1);
        } else {
            long[] pattern = {0, vibrate, vibrate_delay};
            sensorVibrator.vibrate(pattern, 1);
        }

        Log.i("IE LightDetect.", "Lux: " + luxValue);
        handler.postDelayed(this, vibrate_delay);
    }
};
```

}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting the light value in `onSensorChanged()` you are not saving the value globally, there u r using `float x = event.values[0]` which is just creating a local variable inside the function, and not the global one..try ditching the `float` from there, use `x = event.values[0]` instead of `float x = event.values[0]`..the it will save the value in the global variable and that you will use where you calculating vibration..